# Can I use @IBOutlets in Protocols (Swift)

Tags: swift, protocols, iboutlet

I have a small protocol defined in the following manner:

```
import UIKit

protocol HasMeterAnimation {
    func animateMeter(scrollableView: UIScrollView)
}
```

It's implementation requires the use of IBOutlets:

```
func animateMeter(scrollableView: UIScrollView) {

    let maxYPosTableview = scrollableView.frame.height + scrollableView.frame.origin.y
    let progressBarRect = self.progressBar.frame
    let rectOfProgressBarInParentView =  self.convert(progressBarRect, to: scrollableView.superview)
    let maxYPosMeter = rectOfProgressBarInParentView.origin.y + progressBarRect.height

    if maxYPosTableview > maxYPosMeter {
        if progressBar.isHidden == false {
            progressBar.animateProgressBar()
            model.shouldMeterAnimate = false
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to know if there is a way for me to write this implementation in a protocol extension using the IBOutlets... something like this:

```
    protocol HasMeterAnimation {

        @IBOutlet var progressBar:AnimatedProgressBar! { get set }
        var model: ListItem! { get set }

        func animateMeter(scrollableView: UIScrollView)
    }

extension HasMeterAnimation {

            func animateMeter(scrollableView: UIScrollView) {

                let maxYPosTableview = scrollableView.frame.height + scrollableView.frame.origin.y
                let progressBarRect = self.progressBar.frame
                let rectOfProgressBarInParentView =  self.convert(progressBarRect, to: scrollableView.superview)
                let maxYPosMeter = rectOfProgressBarInParentView.origin.y + progressBarRect.height

                if maxYPosTableview > maxYPosMeter {
                    if progressBar.isHidden == false {
                        progressBar.animateProgressBar()
                        model.shouldMeterAnimate = false
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tried many ways but keeps giving me errors. Thanks

Comment: Do you have errors if you remove the `@IBOutlet`? It can't be helpful here. What errors are you receiving?

Comment: I solved it. The accepted answer is right... IBOutlets makes no sense in protocol. I just defined a property in the protocol and fulfilled as an IbOutlet in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBOutlet is just a keyword to let the interface builder know that you would like to reference an object from the interface builder in your class for example in your ViewController,View etc. In any other context IBOutlet does not make any sense. When you define properties in your protocol you also don't mark them as force unwrapped. When you don't mark a property explicitly as an optional then the property has to have a value at runtime, otherwise you can't compile your code. The interface builder marks its outlets as force unwrapped because they don't have values at compile time and are resolved at runtime.

Comment: While all totally correct, I think the answer to the question is really just the first two sentences. Any IBOutlet belongs to a view or a view controller (which happen to be classes) - an IBOutlet belonging to anything else makes no sense.

Comment: @ok404 so if I defined a property in my protocol... can I use it as an iboutlet in my controller??.. would tell me that the protocol is satisfied?

Comment: It's worth noting that in ObjC, `IBOutlet` is literally a #define macro that is replaced with nothing (it's literally empty). Swift couldn't do that (no preprocessor), so it needed an attribute, but the concept is the same. It's *only* purpose is to let Xcode know that that it's something you'd like to connect UI elements to using the mouse. It has no compile-time or runtime influence on the system at all (that might not be 100% true in Swift; I think it may automatically inject `@objc`). But it definitely doesn't influence protocol conformance.